# I want to only retrieve namespace of an index as vector store, not create

Tags: python, langchain, pinecone

Below is a python function offered by LangChain to insert embedded documents into a namespace in Pinecone index:

```
index = Pinecone.from_documents(docs, embeddings, index_name=index_name, namespace=namespace)
```

I want to use this exact instance of "index" in another Python file at a different time in the user flow. Is there a way I can retrieve the index object instead of inserting + retrieving? Object type of index is: langchain_community.vectorstores.pinecone.Pinecone